# Unset session deletes all saved items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Reading a lot about sessions and how to add and remove items. I see there are a lot of different way's to get this done. I'm having the same problem.

I hope someone here could help me out with this one. I've come along way from nothing to where I am now with the help of this community (thanks!).

This is my problem, I hope I can explain it so you can understand.

Let say I have a shop that sells t-shirts and pants. When I save a t-hirt item to my cart it display's it like it should. But I'm not able to remove the item. If I then filter my page for pans (this triggers an AJAX event) and try to remove the t-shirt, the item is removed. But **ALL** items are removed not just the one I clicked on to remove.

Here is my HTML to add a product:

```
<button type="submit" 
  class="btn btn-primary text-right add-product showtoast"
    data-target="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" 
      data-attribute="<?php the_title(); ?>" 
         data-product="<?php the_title(); ?>">
         Add to cart
</button>
```

And this is the HTML to remove an item:

```
<div class="echo-product">
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?>
    <input type="submit" class="delete-product" value="Remove">
</div>
```

These are my Javascripts to add and remove items:

```
$('.add-product').click(function() {
    var productName = $(this).data('product');
        $.post('http://example.com/reload.php?addparam', 
        {productName: productName}, function(data) {
            $('.txtHint').html(data);
    })
});

$('.delete-product').click(function() {
    var productName = $(this).data('product');
        $.post('http://examples.com/reload.php?delparam', 
        {productName: productName}, function(data) {
            $('.txtHint').html(data);
    })
});
```

And last but not least, my reload.php script:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!array_key_exists('products', $_SESSION) || !is_array($_SESSION['products'])) {
    $_SESSION['products'] = [];
}

$productName = array_key_exists('productName', $_POST) ? (string) $_POST['productName'] : '';

if(isset($_GET['delparam'])){
   unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);
}
if(isset($_GET['addparam'])){
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $productName;
}
?>

    <?php foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as $product): ?>
        <div class="echo-product">
          <i style="color:#F60;padding-right:20px;" class="fa fa-anchor" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <?php echo htmlspecialchars($product); ?>
             <input type="submit" class="delete-product" value="Remove">
         </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Is there anyone that could help me understand why (it looks like) an AJAX event has to take place before I'm able to remove items. And why it removes **ALL** the items when I just click on one item?

Thanks!

Comment: the `delete-product` button does not have any data attributes, so `var productName` will be null in `('.delete-product').click(function(){}`

Comment: I wish I understood what you're saying but I don't. Is there any easy to say what you're saying? @Steve

Comment: @Steve
You mean this: `$('.delete-product').click(function() {
 var productName = null;
  $.post('http://example.com/reload.php?delparam', {productName: productName}, function(data) {
    $('.txtHint').html(data);
 })
});
`

Comment: Look at the html for the add product button. It has three data attributes, the 3rd one is named `data-product`. The javascript function attached to the click event for that button pulls the value of that data attribute. Now look at the html for the delete product button. It has no data attributes, but the javascript function attached to its click event still tries to pull a value from the non existent `data-product` attribute

Comment: Owke. But if I add `data-target="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-attribute="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-product="<?php the_title(); ?>` to the html of the remove button nothing works anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Compare how products are added vs. how they are deleted

```
if(isset($_GET['delparam'])){
   unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName]);
}
if(isset($_GET['addparam'])){
    $_SESSION['products'][] = $productName;
}
```

When adding a product, you just append the productName to an array. The entry receives an numeric index.

When deleting a product you look for the productName as index - but that does not exist!

I'm sure it doesn't answer why all products are removed, but it might help to do things right.

Comment: Adding the products is done in an array right? With the `[]`. So Do I need to do the same with the removal? `unset($_SESSION['products'][][$productName]);`. But doing that doesn't add any products. @Lars Stegelitz

Comment: `$_SESSION['products'][$productName] = $productName;`

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['products'][$productName] = $productName;);` Like this?

Comment: Or did you mean for the `addparam` value.